# CentOS7 on GCE -> WHM 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: cpanel, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've set up a GCE CentOS7 highmem-8 and installed cpanel as root.

I've executed /scripts/build_cpnat
I've set the GCE Firewall rules to allow tcp:2083; tcp:2087; tcp:2089 (SSL ports)

When I go to whm.mydomain.host  I am presented with the standard cPanel login after going through the standard "Your connection is not private" warning bypass.  I login with root and password and it authenticates for just one second: you can see the authenticated green status for a second and then it takes me to 502 (Bad Gateway).

I'm at a loss.  You're help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Stackoverflow deals with programming questions, and although it includes software development tools questions, your question is about cpanel configurationl. Therefore, your question would be better placed in superuser.com which is the appropriate site for these questions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's cpanel config or a network routing issue within the GCE project VM networking settings.  
From localhost I can do "wget domain.com:2087 and it responds with the warning page (as expected) -- from a public space, it hangs and timesout.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry to make that presumption; that's good information to have.